# Azure Mobile App Authentication & Azure AAD B2C

Tags: azure-mobile-services, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Can you use Azure AAD B2C as an Azure App Service Authentication/Authorization Provider?

Regular Azure AD is working fine but I want to take advantage of the auth workflows in the B2C offering.  I'm hoping I can switch out the Azure AD Provider ClientId and IssuerUrl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, as of a few weeks ago, this is possible! More details here: https://cgillum.tech/2016/05/27/app-service-auth-and-azure-ad-b2c/

To summarize, you will simply need to use the "Advanced" configuration in the portal to specify your B2C app's **Application Client ID** as the *Client ID* and specify the generated **Metadata Endpoint for this policy URL** as the *Issuer URL*.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Azure AD B2C with Azure App Service Authentication / Authorization yet.  Sorry!

Comment: We recently added support for this. See the other answer to this question.